# Is there a way to open links from a browser on a separate device?

Tags: browser, iphone, ipad

I open a link in Chrome on my laptop, but I'm leaving, so I want to send it to my iPad to read on the go.

OR

I click a link on my iPhone, and it's Flash, so I want to open in on my desktop.

Is there an easy way, other than emailing myself the link?

(I'm running OS X)

Comment: IM it maybe faster? you would need two different accounts on both your devices but that ought to work..

Answer (score 2):

Probably use [Instapaper](http://instapaper.com) ?

Comment: I do use instapaper, but it doesn't really solve "I click a link on my iPhone, and it's Flash, so I want to open in on my desktop."

Comment: @ironkeith why not ? CLick a link, opens flash - so use instapaper bookmarklet to read it later.

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal, but my solution is to keep a running list of sites to browse on another computer that is synced via the Web.  I use SimpleNote on my iPad and iPhone and JustNotes on my Mac to move links this way.  The syncing is so fast it seems instantaneous.

The [Firefox Home](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/mobile/home/) app is also a newer solution to this same problem.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.handoffapp.com/ solves the PC->iPhone link sending problem, and does so very well.

http://pushbrowserapp.com/ does it both ways, and it is also quite nice to use.